# Dockerized certbot can not find mounted directory

Tags: docker-compose, web-deployment, lets-encrypt, docker-volume, certbot

I'm trying to deploy my service on a vm and I have this part in my docker-compose.yaml:

```
certbot:
container_name: certbot
image: certbot/certbot:v1.9.0
logging:
  driver: "json-file"
  options:
    max-size: 500m
volumes:
  - {vm_path}/certbot/certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
  - {vm_path}/certbot/certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
  - {vm_path}/nginx/certbot-web-root:/var/www/certbot/html
  - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
  - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
command:
  - certonly
  - --webroot
  - -w /var/www/certbot/html
  - --email={email}
  - --agree-tos
  - --no-eff-email
  - --dry-run
  - -d {domain}
```

but when I run `docker-compose up`, I get this error from certbot:

`certbot        |  /var/www/certbot/html does not exist or is not a directory`

also the directory `{vm_path}/nginx/certbot-web-root:/var/www/certbot/html` exists on my vm and is absolute.

------UPDATE:
My VM's OS is Ubuntu 18.04.
I checked `docker-compose config` and there is no problem in it.
Also the result of `run ls -l /var/www/certbot`:

```
 certbot        | total 4
 certbot        | drwxr-xr-x    2 1001     1001     4096 Nov  4 10:54 html
```

and also the `/var/www/certbot/html/` exists and is empty.

Comment: Try to run `docker-compose config` and verify that the volume paths are as you expect them to be. If that is good then try to start the container replacing the command with something like `ls -l /var/www/certbot`. This way you can look inside the container and see better what was mounted

Comment: @Mihai Thanks, I couldn't find anything unusual in ```docker-compose config```. How should I run ```ls -l /var/www/certbot```? I couldn't run it with command in docker-compose. I got this output: ```certbot        | usage: 
certbot        |   certbot [SUBCOMMAND] [options] [-d DOMAIN] [-d DOMAIN] ...
```

Comment: You need to also overwrite the entrypoint. Just add `entrypoint: ls -l /var/www/certbot` and remove the `command` completely

Comment: @Mihai Thanks. The output is: 
`certbot        | total 4
certbot        | drwxr-xr-x    2 1001     1001          4096 Nov  4 10:54 html`

Comment: And if you look inside the `html` folder? what is your host OS?

Comment: @Mihai It's empty: `certbot        | total 0`

Comment: I thought so. And probably you are running on Windows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224085/discussion-between-no746-and-mihai).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. The problem is the command section syntax, it should be:

```
command:
  - certonly
  - --webroot
  - -w
  - /var/www/certbot/html
  - --email={email}
  - --agree-tos
  - --no-eff-email
  - --dry-run
  - -d
  - {domain}
```